# Laravel Eloquent: orderBy related table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to order result of eloquent by field on the other related table.
I have users table. Every user has one profile. Profile has sponsored (which is boolean) field. So when I would like to get all users, I want to display first sponsored users, then non sponsored.

```
public function profile(){
 return $this->hasOne('App\Doctor');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:
1)You have to join tables,

```
User::join('profiles','users.id','=','profile.user_id')->orderBy('sponsored','DESC')->get()
```

2)Order by eager loading

```
User::with(array('profile' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('sponsored', 'DESC');
    }))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
User::leftJoin('profile', 'user.id', '=', 'profile.user_id')
    ->orderBy('profile.sponsored', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend not using table joins as it would fail you on the scale.

A better solution is to get users, get their profiles and then sort them using laravel collection methods.

You can use this sample to achieve this solution.

```
//get all users
$users = User::all();
//extract your users Ids
$userIds = $users->pluck('id')->toArray();
//get all profiles of your user Ids
$profiles = Profile::whereIn('user_id', $userIds)->get()->keyBy('user_id');
//now sort users based on being sponsored or not
$users = $users->sort(function($item1, $item2) use ($profiles) {
  if($profiles[$item1->id]->sponsored == 1 && $profiles[$item2->id]->sponsored == 1){
    return 0;
  }
  if($profiles[$item1->id]->sponsored == 1) return 1;
  return -1;
});
```

You can check [this link](https://stillat.com/blog/2018/04/22/laravel-5-collections-sorting-a-collection-with-sort) which explains on laravel collection sorts.

Answer (score 0):

```
$order = 'desc';
    $users = User::join('profile', 'users.id', '=', 'profile.id')
   ->orderBy('profile.id', $order)->select('users.*')->get();
```